# How to change the marker size in lmplot

Tags: python, seaborn, lmplot

I am trying to change the size of the `lmplot` markers in seaborn. I have tried passing 's' or 'size' as arguments and neither of them work.

```
lm = sns.lmplot(x="totalX",y="NormI", hue="Data Type", data=df, palette="Set1", legend_out=False, S=20)
```

I have tried "s", "markersize", "size" I get no effect. I want to make the data points larger on the plot. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You want to use `scatter_kws={"s": 100}`

As in:

```
lm = sns.lmplot(x = "totalX", y = "NormI", hue = "Data Type", data = df, palette="Set1", legend_out=False, scatter_kws={"s": 100})
```

You can amend the integer value (currently 100) to change the size of the markers.

I don't know what your `hue` or `palette` data are, but this should work nonetheless.

Answer (score 9):

I know this question specifies `lmplot` but thought I would add an answer for how to do this with a seaborn `scatterplot`.

```
df = sns.load_dataset("anscombe")
sp = sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y", hue="dataset", data=df)
```

[image]

And to change the size of the points you use the `s` parameter

```
sp = sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y", hue="dataset", data=df, s=100)
```

[image]