# 3d seaborn lmplot using variable marker size

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe with three columns (A,B,C). I have drawn a regression line of A vs B using

```
sns.lmplot(x='A', y='B', data = df, x_bins=10, ci=None)
```

I am using 10 bins and no confidence interval as I have a large number (~5million) datapoints.

I would like to show the value of C on this plot. C has nothing to do with the regression of A against B. I would just like to show C by making the marker size of each bin equal to the average value of C within that bin.

It seems seaborn doesn't have a markersize parameter that can be set equal to a column of the dataframe. Is this even possible?

I cam across [this stackexchange post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796451/changing-the-marker-size-in-python-seaborn-lmplot) which suggests using `scatter_kws={"s": 100}` to set the marker size. However, when I tried `scatter_kws={"s": df['C']}` it threw an error.

If this is not possible in seaborn, are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: do you really wanna a 3d plot or just overlap c on the top of a and b plot? If not, maybe correct your post title.

Comment: @steven i just want to overlap c on the a and b plot